# Mixamo animation sharing between meshes

Tags: animation, armature

how to associate a mixamo animation to another mesh in blender 2.8? Both meshes have the same mixamo skeleton, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the two armatures are in the same file, simply select your second skeleton, turn a dopesheet window into an action editor, and select your Mixamo animation in its dropdown menu.

If the animation is in another file, choose append in the file menu, select the origin file, go to its "action" folder and select the animation.

Then do the same procedure.

[image]

Comment: Hi Josh, thanks for your support, I am going to try it!

Comment: C'mon, I'm gonna reach 10.000 :).

Comment: Cool! working perfectly, thanks a lot!

Comment: If so, please mark the answer as accepted!

Comment: Done!, thanks again!

Comment: Hi Josh, also regarding animation I posted this question, https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/153058/image-material-animation-2-8-eevee, do you know how this works? Thanks in advance